# Passing three parameters into PHP function returning 0

Tags: php, concatenation, string-concatenation

I'm writing a function `buildUserName`  that receives three parameters: `$firstName, $middleName, $lastName`

The function looks like this:

```
function buildUserName($firstName, $middleName, $lastName) {
    echo $firstName + $middleName + $lastName;
}
```

I call the function like so:

```
buildUserName("Bob", "Ryan", "Brown");
```

Expected output:

```
BobRyanBrown
```

Actual Output:

```
0
```

Why is this? How do I change my code so that I produce the expected output?

Comment: `+` is addition in PHP. `.` is for concatenation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use `+`, maybe try something like:

```
function buildUserName($firstName, $middleName, $lastName) {
    $Name = "";
    if(isset($firstName)){
     $Name .= $firstName
    }
    if(isset($middleName)){
     $Name .= $middleName
    }
    if(isset($lastName)){
     $Name .= $lastName
    }
    return $Name;
} 
echo buildUserName("Bob", "Ryan", "Brown");
```

Result would be: `BobRyanBrown`

Answer (score 0):

Functions in `php` can use `echo` but it's standard to use `return`.
To concatenate strings you should use `.`, **not** `+` (used for addition), or put the variables inside double quotes `"$var1 $var2 $var3"`, something like:

```
function buildUserName($firstName, $middleName, $lastName) {
    return "$firstName $middleName $lastName";
} 

echo buildUserName("Pedro", "Guerreiro", "Lobito");
```

Answer (score 0):

`+` is addition, not string concatenation in PHP. You'd want to have `.` instead.

```
function buildUserName($firstName, $middleName, $lastName) {
    echo $firstName . $middleName . $lastName;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In PHP `+` is used for addition.
You have to use `.` to combine strings, like this:

```
function buildUserName($firstName, $middleName, $lastName) {
    echo $firstName . $middleName . $lastName;
}
```